# Make an installer install in 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, installer

I have Windows 7 64-bit and I have an installer for a program, but I want to have the program install the 32 bit version of itself instead of the 64 bit version.  Anybody know how to force an installer to think you're running 32-bit windows?

Comment: great idea! anyone?

Comment: Compatibility mode?

Comment: Do you have a reason as to why you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

What program is it? Usually there are separate installers for 32bit and 64bit just bundled into one MSI. If it came on a CD try browsing around the disk to find the 32bit installer. If you downloaded it, check your temp folder when you first open the installer or use the [MSIEXEC command line options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(WS.10).aspx) to extract the files into a temp folder.

Comment: It's not an MSI installer but I tried it anyway, failed.  The program is called yaTimer [http://www.nbdtech.com/yaTimer/Download.htm]

Comment: That app appears to be build using the .NET Framework 3.0. You might want to check out these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394553/can-an-x64-computer-have-both-the-x86-and-x64-net-runtime-installed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507268/force-x86-clr-on-any-cpu-net-assembly